# Verify if file is created between 2 hours

Tags: c#

I need to verify if file is created between 2 hours and 6 hours o'clock, for this, I use this solution:

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"X:\").GetFiles("*.*");
foreach(var i in files)
{
    var time = i.CreationTime.ToString("HH:mm").Split(':');
    var hora = Convert.ToInt32(time[0]);
    var minu = Convert.ToInt32(time[1]);

    if ((hora >= 2 && hora <= 6) && (minu <= 59))
       Console.WriteLine("File created before 6:30 in the morning\n\t{0} -> {1}", i.Name, i.CreationTime.ToString());
}
```

But, I considerate this solution very very poor, I want to know if have a more better way to make this verification...

Comment: Why do you consider this to be a poor solution? There doesn't appear to be anything particularly wrong with it to me.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.hour(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What purpose should this serve? Just for the completeness: creation file is relative to the system and can be set to any value.

Comment: coordinated universal time or local time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreationTime` is your key. All you need to do is the following:

```
if ((i.CreationTime.Hour >= 2 && i.CreationTime.Hour <= 6)
    && (i.CreationTime.Minute <= 59))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice to state the condition only once:

```
TimeSpan okFrom = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0),
         okTo =   new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0);

var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"X:\").GetFiles("*.*");
foreach (var i in files)
{
    if (i.CreationTime.TimeOfDay >= okFrom && i.CreationTime.TimeOfDay <= okTo)
        Console.WriteLine("File created before 6:30 in the morning\n\t{0} -> {1}", i.Name, i.CreationTime.ToString());
}
```